# How to delete only those rows without any relation in other tables in Prisma?

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I have a table that can have relations in other tables in certain cases but not all the rows will have relations.How do I delete only those rows without any relation in any other table in Prisma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [deleteMany](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/crud#delete-multiple-records) function in combination with a filter that checks for the absence of related records.
For example:

Assuming you have the following schema:

```
model Parent {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  children  Child[]
}

model Child {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  parentId  Int
  parent    Parent   @relation(fields: [parentId], references: [id])
}
```

To delete Parent records that have no related Child records, you can do it like this:

```js
const deletedParents = await prisma.parent.deleteMany({
  where: {
    children: {
      none: {}, // This filter matches records with no related children
    },
  },
});
```

This will delete all Parent records that have no Child records associated with them.